# ProtectedData.Unprotect (DPAPI) stops working after password change

Tags: c#

Suppose I encrypt data and write it to a file like this:

```
byte[] encrypted =
    ProtectedData.Protect(plain, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, encrypted);
```

Decrypting is as straightforward:

```
byte[] encrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
byte[] decrypted =
    ProtectedData.Unprotect(encrypted, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

Now when I change my windows password between the calls to Protect and Unprotect, Unprotect will throw an exception. I do want the encrypted data to be linked to my user account, but I also want it to survive password changes.

I guess I have to hand the data over to Windows rather than writing it to my own file, so that Windows can re-encrypt it on password changes. I just can't find the documentation that tells me how. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*How* do you change the password? Using the normal procedure and specifying the old password should work with `ProtectedData`, while setting a new password under computer management wouldn't.

[image: Set Password dialog with warning]

Comment: That was quick! Thanks mate, that was the problem. If I let the user change their own password it works.

Comment: Quick Q if i reset the account's password, then later set it back to its old password again, would Unprotect would start working again?

Comment: The dialog states _irreversible loss_, so it wouldn't work.