# How to make a file unreadable by user only when saved + VB.net/C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, cryptography

How to make a file unreadable by user only when saved to a disk, say on C drive?

Comment: Just pass the file through `CryptoStream` whenever you read or write it.  But you will need to figure out where to store the key.  Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: Encryption doesnt make data invisible to human eyes, just unreadable.  So where is the data?  Do you know how to save it to a file?  Is it just text?

Comment: If the file is for a single user on a single Windows machine, consider the Data Protection API.

Comment: @Plutonix, I meant 'unreadable'. Thank you for the precision.  The data is created by the application at runtime and saved to the location on a disk where user stores information, eg. C drive.  It is this data I wanted to save encrypted. But then when the application opens back this file, it needs to be decrypted. I just want the saved data unreadable by human eyes

Comment: @Tom Blodget, can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

If the data originates in the application and is only for the current user on the same Windows machine,

```
// using System.Security.Cryptography;

var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + 
    @"/user data that only a program run by this user can read.dat";
Console.WriteLine(path);
var entropy = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("See http://security.stackexchange.com/a/58121");


var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
    @"Data to be stored in a way that only programs that run under 
    this account can decrypt but nobody's eyes can understand. But 
    if an admin forces a password change, it's irretrievable 
    (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4755929/2226988).");
File.WriteAllBytes(path, ProtectedData.Protect(
    data, 
    entropy, 
    DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));


var readBack = ProtectedData.Unprotect(
    File.ReadAllBytes(path), 
    entropy, 
    DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBack));
```